# How to remove an item in a string array in firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am trying to remove an item in a string array in firestore with:

```
   db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(request.user.username)
    .update({
      clients: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(clientEmail),
    })
```

it is giving me the error in the firebase logs:

```
Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type "FieldValue$1" (found in field "clients"). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator). at WriteBatch.update (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:374:23) at DocumentReference.update (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:377:14) at exports.deleteOneClient (/workspace/APIs/users.js:771:6) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) at next (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13) at /workspace/util/auth.js:28:14 at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5
```

the data looks like this in the document in

```
clients:
    0: "test@test.com"
    1: "test@test.com"
    2: "test@test.com"
```

I believe the issue is as simple as me using the array remove wrong. the clientEmail is just the string value that i want to remove in the array. Based on examples I've seen, I might just be inputting params wrong.

Comment: I dont know anything about firebase but does if `firebase.firestore.FieldValue` is just an array, cant you remove the value at the matching index? `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.splice(firebase.firestore.FieldValue.length - 1, 1)` is an example to remove the last value in the array

Comment: Are you using the Admin SDK? If yes, can you show how you import the module and initialize a Firebase admin app?